# sysctl doesn't creates file in proc

Tags: linux, kernel-module, sysctl, kernel-mode

To communicate in kernel mode and user space, I am using [this C program](http://people.ee.ethz.ch/~arkeller/linux/code/sysctl.c). I am using following  Makefile to create `.ko` file to load.

```
bj-m   := sysctl_test.o

KDIR    := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD    := $(shell pwd)

default:
        $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules

clean:
        $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) clean
```

After successful execution, and loading the `.ko` file, it should have create `/proc/sys/net/test` directory, and `value1` and `value2` file in that directory.

When I load this module, it doesn't create any file or directory. Am I doing something wrong here or code need some changes?

I have tried by modifying values in structures as:

```
static ctl_table test_net_table[] = {
        {
                ... 
                .procname       = "/proc/sys/net/test",
                ...
        },
        { .ctl_name = 0 }
};

static ctl_table test_root_table[] = {
        {
                ...
                .procname       = "/proc/sys/net/",
                ...
        },
        { .ctl_name = 0 }
};
```

The original values was `test` and `net` respectively.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
bj-m   := sysctl_test.o
```

to

```
obj-m   := sysctl_test.o
```

it worked for me.

PS:Its an old question, but I update answer for those who come across same error and stop her.